# How to make apk secure and what is the most unique identifier an app has?

Tags: android, md5, public-key-encryption

MD5 fingerprint of any app can be easily acquired using keytool. Then what is the most unique identifier an app has?

I am trying to build a client server app and I want a secure the communications.
My problem revolves around these two assumptions - 
1) Someone can reverse engineer my app and understand how I interact with server webservices
2) My app can be simply uninstalled and replaced with malicious app with similar package name.

The system can easily compromised using these two loopholes.

My solution to these problems was transmitting MD5 signature of my app to the server. The MD5 signature will be conveyed to server before hand. MD5 signature is unique for every app, But there is big problem in this approach. MD5 signature of any apk can be generated using keytool. Anyone may pull my apk and generate MD5 and use it in the webservices communication.

What is the unique identifier of an android app?
Package name and MD5 fingerprint can be easily compromised!

Comment: What kind of attack are you trying to prevent... someone attacking other users of your app, or a user "attacking" their own installation?

Comment: You haven't provided a whole lot of details, but sending the same data every time (your app signature) as a form of validation doesn't seem like a particularly good idea. Nor does automatically trusting that you're talking to the right server. You might want to look into something like [Challenge-response authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge%E2%80%93response_authentication#Cryptographic_techniques). Perhaps this question is better suited for http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: user attacking their own installation.

Comment: My problem can be broken down into two problems -
1) User and server should uniquely identify themselves
2) The identification of entities should not employ any cryptographic nonce or logic that can be reversed engineered

Comment: I don't think there's anything you can do about either of them.

Comment: If someone is motivated enough it's just a matter of time before they RE your app. You can't really stop that.

Comment: you can avoid the chance of reverse engineering by applying proguard for your app. Try this link http://1belong2jesus.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to be sure that you are talking to your client app at server end.

[Verify Back-End Calls from Android](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html). This link could be helpful as it gives high confidence for such a case. (HTTPS is must here)

Comment: This sounds promising. Will try this out.

Answer (score 1):

As an additional step for @Maddy 's answer, you might think about tamper resistance/integrity protection techniques, that will make your app inoperable in case somebody tried to modify it.  DexProtector (http://dexprotector.com) could be the solution here. The slides under the [link](http://www.slideshare.net/IvanKinash/english-final-35690515) also should be helpful.

N.B.
I am Licel's CEO, thus I am affiliated with DexProtector.

Answer (score 0):

First question

**1)** My app can be simply uninstalled and replaced with malicious app with similar package name.

**best approach is probably the use of ANDROID_ID**

Try this  link http://blog.vogella.com/2011/04/11/android-unique-identifier/
Check this also  http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

Solution for the second issue

**2)** Someone can reverse engineer my app and understand how I interact with server webservices

**Use DexGuard, which can make reverse engineering even harder, like by encrypting strings**

https://www.saikoa.com/dexguard

**Proguard**

“The ProGuard tool shrinks, optimizes, and obfuscates your code by removing unused code and renaming classes, fields, and methods with semantically obscure names. The result is a smaller sized .apk file that is more difficult to reverse engineer.”

When you create android project.

```
1. proguard.cfg file is automatically generated in the root directory of the project.
2. The default configuration file only covers general cases, so customize as per your needs.
```

**Enable it**

“Set the proguard.config  property in the /project.properties file. The path can be an absolute path or a path relative to the project’s root.”

```
 Case1:    Just add proguard.config=proguard.cfg if the proguard.cfg is in projects root path.
 Case2:    Configure from other location  [proguard.config=/path/to/proguard.cfg]
```

Remove the “#” (or uncomment) the proguard configuring statement in project.properties. Which will be in commented initially.

Customize it. try this link http://1belong2jesus.wordpress.com/

Comment: I've reverse-engineered libraries that were obfuscated with Proguard.  It only adds a few hours of work.  By necessity, things like literal strings and public identifiers will not be obfuscated.  You just find something recognizable and go to work with Eclipse's rename tool.

Comment: Thanks Deniz. But Device ID is an unique identifier for the device rather than the app. I want to uniquely identify the app.